# Combinatorics : counting number of arrangements

Tags: combinatorics

I am new to combinatorics and I would like some help on the following:

> We have $n$ letters "A" and $k$ letters "B". How many different arrangements of length $n + k$ can be constructed such that there is no arrangement with at least two consequtive letters "B"?

Comment: Exactly two, or at least two?

Comment: .. with at least two consequtive "B"

Comment: It will be $ {(n+1)}\choose{k} $ $\\$ for detail theory can refferance check here (http://www.mathsdiscussion.com/permutation-with-restriction/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main challenge with combinatorics is figuring out how to frame your problem in terms of things that are easy to count.  Sometimes there are many different ways to frame it, so it can be interesting.  Here's how I would approach this problem.

Imagine your $n$ A letters in a row with gaps between them.  There are then $n+1$ spots where the B's can be placed.  We cannot place two B's in the same spot because then they would be consecutive.  So if $k>n+1$, there are no possible arrangements. 
 Otherwise, the number of ways to place $k$ items into $n+1$ spots without repetition is $n+1\choose k$.

Comment: I love the first paragraph of this answer, and would add that the 'many different ways to frame it' is one of the canonical ways of proving combinatorial identities - counting the same thing in different ways.

Comment: (Also, of course, if $k\gt n+1$, then the number of ways to place those items is _still_ $n+1\choose k$, just vacuously.)